# css flex-box nested layout have issue

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, styled-components

I can't using flex-box well.

This is current state :

[image: current state]

I  want this flex layout :
[image: What I want]

This is my code :

Lobby.js (Container)

```
const TopBlock = styled.div`
    display: flex;
`;

const Lobby = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <TopBlock>
                <CreateRoom />
                <Profile />
            </TopBlock>
        </>
    )
}
```

Profile.js

```
const ProfileBlock = styled.div`
    
`;

const Profile = () => {
    return (
        <ProfileBlock>
            <p>hello0</p>
            <p>hello1</p>
            <p>hello2</p>
        </ProfileBlock>
    )
}
```

What should I do? ..T_T

Comment: What styles do you have in`Profile.js`?

Comment: there is no style yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think , `ProfileBlock` should be wrapped and put into your `<p>hello</p>`. Because if using `flexbox` for `ProfileBlock` look like a container in this case for grouping inside the container we need `wrapper`. [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-frog-icjvn?file=/src/Profile.js:150-172)

**Lobby.js (Container)**

```
const TopBlock = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
`;

export const Lobby = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <TopBlock>
        <CreateRoom />
        <Profile />
      </TopBlock>
    </>
  ); 
};
```

**Profile.js**

```
const ProfileBlock = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  border: 3px solid red;
  div {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  p {
   width: 200px;
   display: flex;
   color: black;
   padding: 15px;
   border: 2px solid blue;
  }
`;

export const Profile = () => {
  return (
    <ProfileBlock>
      <div className="profile-wrapper">
        <p>hello0</p>
        <p>hello1</p>
        <p>hello2</p>
      </div>
    </ProfileBlock>
  );
};
```